# Composing an average stream piecewise

Tags: algorithm

I have a list of `n` floating point streams each having a different size.
The streams can be be composed together using the following rules:
You can put a stream starting at any point in time (its zero before it started). You can use the same stream few times (it can overlap itself and even be in the same position few times) and you are allowed to not use a certain stream at all.
e.g.:
input streams:

```
1 2 3 4
2 4 5 6 7
1 5 6
```

Can be composed like:

```
  1 2 3 4
1 5 6
        1 5 6
```

After the placements an output stream is composed by the rule that each output float equals to the square root of the sum of the square of each term.
e.g.:
If the streams at a position are:

```
1
2
3
```

The output is:

```
sqrt(1*1 + 2*2 + 3*3) = sqrt(14) = 3.74...
```

So for the the example composition:

```
  1 2 3 4
1 5 6
        1 5 6
```

The output is:

```
1 5.09 6.32 3 4.12 5 6
```

What I have is the output stream and the input streams. I need to compute the composition that lead to that output. an exact composition doesn't have to exists - I need a composition as close as possible to the output (smallest accumulated difference).
e.g.:
Input:
Stream to mimic:

```
1 5.09 6.32 3 4.12 5 6
```

and a list:

```
1 2 3 4
2 4 5 6 7
1 5 6
```

Expected output:

```
Stream 0 starting at 1,
Stream 2 starting at 0,
Stream 2 starting at 4.
```

This seems like an NP problem, is there any fast way to solve this? it can be somewhat brute force (but not totally, its not theoretic problem) and it can give not the best answer as long as its close enough.

The algorithm will be usually used with stream to mimic with very long length (can be few megabytes) while it will have around 20 streams to be composed from, while each stream will be around kilobyte long.

Comment: You say "square root of the sum of the *cube* of each term" but your equation shows "square root of the sum of the *square* of each term" -- which is it?

Comment: Something about this makes me think "solve it in the frequency domain", although no specific solution comes to mind.  Is this audio data you are working with?

Comment: @j_random_hacker: its the square, my mistake

Comment: @AShelly: yea it is. I need to compose a music file from very limited set of sounds.

Comment: @Dani, if you're trying to find matches to music and the inputs are waveform samples then your similarity criterion is wrong I'm afraid.  Amplitude samples are conceptually signed numbers and your current approach will consider x at some position a good match even when the output is -x.  If the numbers are all positive, that's just because they're encoded as offset-adjusted positive numbers, and assuming you use a cost function like least squares to score matches, your current approach will "try hard" to match large positive amplitudes and "barely try" to match large negative amplitudes.

Comment: The solution will probably be very different depending on the context.   Are you trying to assemble a bunch of dog barks into '[Jingle Bells'](http://www.scamperingpaws.com/dogsbarkingjinglebells.shtml),  do something instrumental like [MIDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI), or turn random noise into the [latest pop hit](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0)?

Comment: Also, amplitudes add together when you play two sounds at the same time, so you should be looking for an arrangement of sounds such that they *sum* to (nearly) the desired amplitude at each point, rather than what you're doing at the moment, which looks like a strange variant of Euclidean distance.

Comment: @AShelly: I'm doing pretty much "assemble a bunch of dog barks into 'Jingle Bells'"

Comment: The problem is underconstrained.  For any given stream, isn't a correct answer just: that same stream?  Are you specifying any constraints on the components?  I didn't see that.

Comment: @Mike Sokolov: the answer is not the stream itself, but rather how to place the components so when they composed they will be equal to input stream.

Comment: @Dani yes I understood that.  What I am saying is that there are an infinite number of possible answers, and no way to prefer any of them is specified.  Therefore, given an input stream, a valid solution would be the single component that is equal to the input stream, no?

Comment: @mike sokolov: there is no component that's equal to the input stream. The components are a predefined fixed array, you can only use a component from that array.

Comment: ah I missed that - thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

I think you can speed up a greedy search a bit over the obvious. First of all, square each element in all of the streams involved. Then you are looking for a sum of squared streams that looks a lot like the squared target stream. Suppose that "it looks like" is the euclidean distance between the squared streams, considered as vectors.

Then we have (a-b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2a.b. So if we can find the dot product of two vectors quickly, and we know their absolute size, we can find the distance quickly. But using the FFT and the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem, we can work out a.b_i where a is the target stream and b_i is stream b at some offset of i, by using the FFT to convolve a reversed version of b - for the cost of doing an FFT on a, an FFT on reversed b, and an FFT on the result, we get a.b_i for every offset i.

If we do a greedy search, the first step will be to find the b_i that makes (a-b_i)^2 smallest and subtract it from a. Then we are looking for a stream c_j that makes (a-b_i-c_j)^2 as small as possible. But this is a^2 + b_i^2 + c_j^2 - 2a.b_i - 2a.c_j + 2b_i.c_j and we have already calculated everything except b_i.c_j in the step above. If b and c are shorter streams it will be cheap to calculate b_i.c_j, and we can use the FFT as before.

So we have a not too horrible way to do a greedy search - at each stage subtract off the stream from the adjusted target stream so far that makes the residual smallest (considered as vectors in euclidean space), and carry on from there. At some stage we will find that none of the streams we have available make the residual any smaller. We can stop there, because our calculation above shows us that using two streams at once won't help either then - this follows because b_i.c_j >= 0, since each element of b_i is >= 0, because it is a square.

If you do a greedy search and are not satisfied, but have more cpu to burn, try Limited Discrepancy Search.

Comment: I'm not really good at this math thing... can you provide pseudo-code or implementation?

Comment: I don't have code that will do this hanging around, and I've just come from a day of writing and debugging code, so I'm not inclined to sit down and write code for other people. You might just possibly find something you can use in a time series library for http://www.r-project.org/ or a Matlab signal processing toolkit, but I can't wholeheartedly recommend that anybody use such things without understanding their insides, especially if there is any doubt that what they have asked for is what they want.

Comment: Some great ideas here, squaring everything is an obvious good point to start, and computing all shifted inner products using FFT is smart.  Didn't follow your expansion of (a-b_i-c_j)^2 though -- I would just compute an updated version of a (the target output sequence) and start over.  Possibly some computation can be avoided in future iterations because FFT is linear, so you can compute FFT(a-b_i) just by subtracting FFT(b_i) from FFT(a).

Comment: The OP said that the target stream was a megabyte long and the minor streams about a kilobyte long. So b_i.c_j is zero for all but a few thousand of the million relative offsets, and can be computed at the cost of roughly 3 2048-point FFTs. If you use the existing FFTs for the megabyte-length target stream, you need to do one million-point inverse FFT after pointwise multiplication. But all this is academic anyway if we don't have the correct objective. For instance, if this is sound, we aren't we multiplying the streams by some parameter to change volume?

Comment: See what you mean, but when you are looking for the kth stream to add in, you will be adding a term inside the (...)^2 that leads to k more of these shorter input-to-input inner products needing to be computed, so I don't expect to see gains unless very few of the input streams suffice to cover the output.  I agree that the problem formulation is broken for the OP's application, but it's an interesting problem nonetheless :)

Comment: Perhaps a better way to reduce the size of FFTs is to deal with the large target vector as a number of chunks each a few times the size of the smaller streams, in which case you are probably right about updating and retrying. If you are interested in it as an academic exercise, you might be interested in following links to compressed sensing and regularised regression e.g. http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/lasso.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_angle_regression and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_%28statistics%29#LASSO_method

Answer (score 0):

If I can use C#, LINQ & the Rx framework's System.Interactive extensions then this works:

First up - define a jagged array for the allowable arrays.

```
int[][] streams =
    new []
    {
        new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, },
        new [] { 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, },
        new [] { 1, 5, 6, },
    };
```

Need an infinite iterator on integers to represent each step.

```
IEnumerable<int> steps =
    EnumerableEx.Generate(0, x => true, x => x + 1, x => x);
```

Need a random number generator to randomly select which streams to add to each step.

```
var rnd = new Random();
```

In my LINQ query I've used these operators:

- Scan^ - runs an accumulator function over a sequence producing an
  output value for every input value
- Where - filters the sequence based on the predicate
- Empty - returns an empty sequence
- Concat - concatenates two sequences
- Skip - skips over the specified number of elements in a sequence
- Any - returns `true` if the sequence contains any elements
- Select - projects the sequence using a selector function
- Sum - sums the values in the sequence

^ - from the Rx System.Interactive library

Now for the LINQ query that does all of the hard work.

```
IEnumerable<double> results =
    steps
        // Randomly select which streams to add to this step
        .Scan(Enumerable.Empty<IEnumerable<int>>(), (xs, _) =>
            streams.Where(st => rnd.NextDouble() > 0.8).ToArray())
        // Create a list of "Heads" & "Tails" for each step
        // Heads are the first elements of the current streams in the step
        // Tails are the remaining elements to push forward to the next step
        .Scan(new
        {
            Heads = Enumerable.Empty<int>(),
            Tails = Enumerable.Empty<IEnumerable<int>>()
        }, (acc, ss) => new
        {
            Heads = acc.Tails.Concat(ss)
                .Select(s => s.First()),
            Tails = acc.Tails.Concat(ss)
                .Select(s => s.Skip(1)).Where(s => s.Any()),
        })
        // Keep the Heads only
        .Select(x => x.Heads)
        // Filter out any steps that didn't produce any values
        .Where(x => x.Any())
        // Calculate the square root of the sum of the squares
        .Select(x => System.Math.Sqrt((double)x.Select(y => y * y).Sum()));
```

Nice lazy evaluation per step - scary though...

Comment: From this code I can't understand what was your idea and what's the amazing part, it's better describe your idea, then show your code.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri - I'll have a go at commenting it a bit later.

Comment: The random part makes me think it's brute force

Comment: @Dani - the random part is just to select a sample from the `streams` jagged array. It's not brute force either. Just uses iterators.

Comment: @Dani - I've added explanation to my algorithm.